# Need to rename many very long file names with variable

Tags: script, powershell

My company gets a list of files every day that we need to process and the file names are almost impossible for our system to deal with. Is there a way to rename these files? I am new to any type of scripting, so I am not sure where to start. I am using a Windows system. I have tried to use Bulk Rename Utility, but I am not able to figure out how to remove the AB_C_D_, and it sometimes makes mistakes for some unknown reason I have not figured out. Is there a way to rename these files using PowerShell?

This is what the file names look like now:

```
Sample1_Sample2_1_05-11-2015_0_Sample3-AB_C_D_045_4_Sample4_123456.pdf
```

This is what I would like to do:

- Remove `Sample1` (which will always be the same)
- Leave `Sample2` so the filename will start with `Sample2` (will always be the same)
- Remove `_1`
- Leave the date (which is a date in the future and will change)
- Remove `0_Sample3` (which is always the same)
  -Leave the page number (045 which will be different on each file) and place it after the date.
  -Remove _4_Sample4_
  -Leave 123456 (this is an identifying number and will be different on each file).

The main problem is that I want to remove the AB_C_D_, and these letters will change. There may be more or less (A_C_D_ for example) 
and I don't know how to remove this part.

So the finished file name will be `Sample2_05-11-2015_045_123456.pdf`

If anyone could assist me with this or point me in the right direction for how to do this, it would be extremely appreciated!

Thanks in advance,
HH-GeekyGal

Comment: [This](http://www.regular-expressions.info) will help you do what you want with BRU or PowerShell.

Answer (score 1):

This Powershell script will rename files the way you need. Save it as `RenameFiles.ps1` and run from the PowerShell console.

Script accepts following arguments:

- **Path**: *Required, existing folder on disk, where your files are stored. You can supply multiple paths.*
- **Recurse**: *Optional switch, controls recursion. If specified, the script will rename files in all subfolders.*
- **WhatIf**: *Optional switch, if specified, script will only report new and old filenames. No renaming will be done.*

Examples (run from the PowerShell console):

- Rename all files in folder `c:\path\to\files`:

  ```powershell
  .\RenameFiles.ps1 -Path 'c:\path\to\files'
  ```
- Rename all `pdf` files in folder `c:\path\to\files`:

  ```powershell
  .\RenameFiles.ps1 -Path 'c:\path\to\files\*.pdf'
  ```
- Rename all `pdf` files in folder `c:\path\to\files`, recurse

  ```powershell
  .\RenameFiles.ps1 -Path 'c:\path\to\files\*.pdf' -Recurse
  ```
- Scan files in multiple folders, recurse, report only (no rename):

  ```powershell
  .\RenameFiles.ps1 -Path 'c:\path\A\*.pdf', 'c:\path\B\*.psd' -Recurse -WhatIf
  ```

`RenameFiles.ps1` script itself:

```powershell
# Arguments accepted by script
Param
(
    # One or multiple paths, as array of strings
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ValueFromPipeline = $true)]
    [string[]]$Path,

    # Recurse switch
    [switch]$Recurse,

    # Whatif switch
    [switch]$WhatIf
)

# This function transforms long file name (w\o extension) to short via regex
function Split-FileName
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param
    (
        # Original file name
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ValueFromPipeline = $true)]
        [string]$FileName
    )

    Begin
    {
        # You can change this block to adapt new rules for file renaming,
        # without modifying other parts of script.

        # Regex to match, capture groups are used to build new file name
        $Regex = '(Sample2).*(\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}).*(?<=[a-z]_)(\d+)(?=_\d+).*(?<=_)(\d+)$'

        # Scriptblock that builds new file name. $Matches is hashtable, but we need array for the format (-f) operator.
        # So this code: @(0..$Matches.Count | ForEach-Object {$Matches[$_]})} transforms it to the array.

        # Basically, we creating a new array of integers from 0 to count of $Matches keys, e.g. @(0,1,2,3,4,5)
        # and passing it down the pipeline. Then, in the foreach loop we output values of $Matches keys which name
        # match the current pipeline object, e.g. $Matches['1'], $Matches['2'], etc.
        # $Matches['0'] holds whole matched string, other keys hold capture groups.

        # This would also work:
        # $NewFileName = {'{0}_{1}_{2}_{3}{4}' -f $Matches['1'], $Matches['2'], $Matches['3'], $Matches['4'], $Matches['5']

        $NewFileName = {'{1}_{2}_{3}_{4}{5}' -f @(0..$Matches.Count | ForEach-Object {$Matches[$_]})}

    }

    Process
    {
        # If original file name matches regex
        if($FileName -match $Regex)
        {
            # Call scriptblock to generate new file name
            . $NewFileName
        }
    }
}

# For each path, get all file objects
Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -Recurse:$Recurse |
    # That are not directory
    Where-Object {!$_.PsIsContainer} |
        # For each file
        ForEach-Object {
            # Try to create new file name
            $NewBaseName = $_.BaseName | Split-FileName

            if($NewBaseName)
            {
                # If file name matched regex and we've got a new file name...

                # Build full path for the file with new name
                $NewFullName = Join-Path -Path $_.DirectoryName -ChildPath ($NewBaseName + $_.Extension)

                if(Test-Path -Path $NewFullName -PathType Leaf)
                {
                    # If such file already exists, show error message
                    Write-Host "File already exist: $NewFullName"
                }
                else
                {
                    # If not, rename it or just show report, depending on WhatIf switch
                    Rename-Item -Path $_.FullName -NewName $NewFullName -WhatIf:$WhatIf -Force
                }
            }
    }
```

Regex used in this script: https://regex101.com/r/hT2uN9/2 (note, that PowerShell's regex by default are not case-sensitive). Copy of regex explanation here:

**Regex**:

```
(Sample2).*(\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}).*(?<=[a-z]_)(\d+)(?=_\d+).*(?<=_)(\d+)$
```

**Sample2** string:

```
1st Capturing group (Sample2)

Sample2 matches the characters Sample2 literally (case insensitive)
```

**Any character** (not captured and not exist in `$Matches` variable):

```
.* matches any character (except newline)
Quantifier: * Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible,
giving back as needed [greedy]
```

**Date**:

```
2nd Capturing group (\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4})

\d{2} match a digit [0-9]
Quantifier: {2} Exactly 2 times
- matches the character - literally

\d{2} match a digit [0-9]
Quantifier: {2} Exactly 2 times
- matches the character - literally

\d{4} match a digit [0-9]
Quantifier: {4} Exactly 4 times
```

**Any character** (not captured and not exist in `$Matches` variable):

```
.* matches any character (except newline)
Quantifier: * Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible,
giving back as needed [greedy]
```

**Number of pages**:

```
(?<=[a-z]_) Positive Lookbehind - Assert that the regex below can be matched

[a-z] match a single character present in the list below
a-z a single character in the range between a and z (case insensitive)
_ matches the character _ literally

3rd Capturing group (\d+)

\d+ match a digit [0-9]
Quantifier: + Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible,
giving back as needed [greedy]

(?=_\d+) Positive Lookahead - Assert that the regex below can be matched
_ matches the character _ literally

\d+ match a digit [0-9]
Quantifier: + Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible,
giving back as needed [greedy]
```

**Any character** (not captured and not exist in `$Matches` variable):

```
.* matches any character (except newline)
Quantifier: * Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible,
giving back as needed [greedy]
```

**Id number**:

```
(?<=_) Positive Lookbehind - Assert that the regex below can be matched
_ matches the character _ literally

4th Capturing group (\d+)

\d+ match a digit [0-9]
Quantifier: + Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible,
giving back as needed [greedy]
```

Comment: Thanks to everyone who gave an answer to my question. Since I am new to any type of scripting, I am going to have to digest this for a few days. This is my first question in this forum, and it was difficult to word it in a way that was understandable.

Answer (score 0):

Like Karan linked, regular expressions are the way to do it. I'm on linux so I'm not sure if powershell has suitable buildins but if not, download sed for windows from sourceforge. It's allaround awesomesauce.

My sed-fu is horribad but this will reformat the original string to new one:

```
sed -r 's/Sample1_(Sample2_)[0-9]*_(..-..-....)_.*-[A-Z_]*(_[0-9][0-9]*_)._Sample4_(.)/\1\2\3\4/'
```

I'm sure there are simpler ways to accomplish the same.

If you can read bash, below is an example how to rename with it:

```
for i in $(ls);do mv $i $(echo $i|sed -r 's/Sample1_(Sample2_)[0-9]*_(..-..-....)_.*-[A-Z_]*(_[0-9][0-9]*_)._Sample4_(.*)/\1\2\3\4/');done
```

No doubt it'll be simple enough to script similar in powershell but that is left as exercise to reader :P

EDIT:typo

EDIT2: Looked over what I wrote and it might be difficult to understand so I'll try and show what I was trying to do:

Overall the regex reads the line and encloses the parts we want to keep in parenthesis. They are called patterns. After the line is read, discard everything except the patterns chosen.

```
sed -r   //-r switch is here only to allow the use of parens without escaping them. It's confusing enough without backslashes.
's/      //s is the command, stands for subtitute. syntax s/[search pattern]/[replace pattern]/. string matching SP is replaced with RP.
         //Here I use the command to match the whole line and save the parts I want.

Sample1_(Sample2_)  //set "Sample2_" as first pattern
[0-9]*_(..-..-....) //read onwards and skip zero or more numerals ([0-9]*) between two underscores. Read xx-xx-xxxx as second pattern where x is any character
_.*-[A-Z_]*(_[0-9][0-9]*_) //after underscore, skip any number of characters (.*) until run across dash. after that, skip any number of capital letters and underscores until you run into underscore followed by more than one numeral and underscore (_[0-9][0-9]*_). Save that as pat 3
._Sample4_(.*) //grab everything after Sample4_ as pat 4
/\1\2\3\4/'   //First slash ends the search pattern for the s command and begin the . After that, \1, \2, \3 and \4 insert patterns we saved in search part discarding the rest. final slash ends the s command.
```

regex is easy to write even if it's hard to read. Which also means it's easy to make mistakes with and hard to debug but you can't have all.

Here's the gist of the shell script in basic/python/pseudocode-ish scribble.

```
for OLDNAME in DIRECTORY
     let NEWNAME = output of sed command with OLDNAME piped as input.
     rename OLDNAME NEWNAME
next
```